# Select ComboBoxItem Using String

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, combobox

I have a ComboBox using `ComboBoxItems` with background colors instead of `<System:String>`.

[image]

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboColors"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Margin="0,135,212,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="103">
    <ComboBoxItem Background="White" Foreground="Black" Content="White"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Background="Gray" Foreground="White" Content="Gray"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Background="#FF262626" Foreground="White" Content="Dark Gray"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Background="Black" Foreground="White" Content="Black"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Background="#FFfdfd02" Content="Yellow"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Background="#FF9aafe4" Content="Blue"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Background="#FFffb0b0" Content="Pink"/>
</ComboBox>
```

---

I can **get** the value of the `ComboBoxItem` like this

```
ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)(mainwindow.cboColors.SelectedValue);
string selected = (string)(selectedItem.Content);
```

---

How do I **set** the ComboBox SelectedItem using a string `"Yellow"`?

```
cboColors.SelectedItem = "Yellow";
```

The ComboBox does not change.

Comment: You need to use the string to identify which object in the ItemSource (comboboxes items) is the one to become the selected item. i.e. cboColors.SelectedItem = cboColors.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Content.Equals("Yellow"));

Comment: @CodexNZ It gives error, "ItemCollection does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'".

Comment: Why have you gone back to hard coded xaml objects instead of a class to represent the items in your combo? The answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703106/pass-combobox-selected-item-as-method-parameter/45703484#45703484 would allow you to use the bound collection as the source for your lookup instead of needing to do what you are attempting. All you would need to do is add properties to your ComboItem class for background and foreground bindings.

Answer (score 2):

using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45703484/2026877) as a starting point:

```
private void SetSelectedComboBoxItem(string itemName)
{
   ComboItem selected = MyComboItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name.Equals(itemName));
  if (selected != null)
  {
    combo.SelectedItem = selected;
  }
  else
  {
    combo.SelectedItem = combo.Items[0];
  }
}
```

OR

```
private void SetSelectedComboBoxItem(string itemName)
{
   ComboItem selected = MyComboItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name.Equals(itemName));
  if (selected != null)
  {
    SelectedItem = selected;
  }
  else
  {
    SelectedItem = combo.Items[0];
  }
}
```

Then Modify your ComboItem class to include the properties you are using for coloring:

```
public class ComboItem
{
  public string Color { get; private set; }

  public SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor { get; private set; }

  public SolidColorBrush ForegroundColor { get; private set; }

  public ComboItem(string color,  SolidColorBrush background, SolidColorBrush foreground)
  {
    Color = color;
    BackgroundColor = background;
    ForegroundColor = foreground;
  }
}
```

and change your list initialization to include the new properties:

```
List<ComboItem> _myComboItems= new List<ComboItem>()
  {
    new ComboItem("White", Brushes.White, Brushes.Black),
    new ComboItem("Gray", Brushes.Gray, Brushes.White),
    new ComboItem("Dark Gray", Brushes.DarkGray, Brushes.White),
    new ComboItem("Black", Brushes.Black, Brushes.White),
    new ComboItem("Yellow", Brushes.Yellow, Brushes.Black),
    new ComboItem("Blue", Brushes.Blue, Brushes.Black),
    new ComboItem("Pink", Brushes.Pink, Brushes.Black)
  };
```

and modify your xaml to have a style applied to the ComboBox like the following (this will apply to all combobox controls in the app done this way):

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Border Name="Border"
                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}"
                BorderBrush="Transparent">
          <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" 
                       TextAlignment="Left" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Color}" 
                       Margin="5,0,0,0"
                       Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}"/>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hopefully I haven't missed anything out.

Comment: Applying the colors is working. I run into 2 problems. Clicking on an item doesn't select it, the box stays empty. And using `SetSelectedComboBoxItem("Yellow")` I get a NullReferenceException. Here is my full example code: XAML https://pastebin.com/raw/dwxn60VW. C# https://pastebin.com/raw/494VMfQe.

Comment: In your xaml you are using both SelectedItem and SelectedIndex, use only one as they will work against each other, even when you select an item, the SelectedIndex value is hardcoded to 0.

Comment: Where is the NullReferenceException occurring? use your debugger to find out what is null and either fix it or protect against it.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `SelectedItem` to a `ComboBoxItem` and not to a `string`. You can select the appropriate ComboBoxItem using some LINQ:

```
cboColors.SelectedItem = cboColors.Items.OfType<ComboBoxItem>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Content.ToString() == "Yellow");
```

The type of the selected item and the items in the `ComboBox` must match.